# How to make a SKSpriteNode only appear by touch?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

How to make a SKSpriteNode only work by touching the screen? 
I have already written 
`var main = SKSpriteNode()` and 
`main = self.childNode(withName: "main") as! SKSpriteNode`

Comment: Please provide more clarity and details/code to your question so people can help you

Comment: You should improve your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just follow the default template provided by XCode,  it does exactly this, except it uses SKShapeNode instead of SKSpriteNode in the latest version

Answer (score 3):

There's three parts to this process.

1. Getting the touch.
   This is probably done in the GameScene's touchesBegan, in which you need to find the position of the touch.
2. Having a Sprite to create. This can be part of a function that creates a SKSprite in the GameScene's top level, so you can call it, or it could be a class of your own that you instance on the touch.
3. Creating, and then Adding the child to the scene.

I think it's the last part, adding the child to the scene, that you might be missing.